# Opencv super resolution error: cv2.error: OpenCV(4.7.0) /io/opencv/modules/dnn/src/net_impl.cpp:1188

Tags: python, opencv, deep-learning, computer-vision, satellite

I would like to upscale Sentinel2 swir images from 20m to 10m to use it with r, g, b and nir bands. To do this, I'm trying opencv super resolution module with this python code:

```
import cv2

img = cv2.imread("img.jp2")

sr = cv2.dnn_superres.DnnSuperResImpl_create()
sr.readModel("EDSR_x2.pb")
sr.setModel("edsr", 2)
result = sr.upsample(img)
cv2.imwrite("result.jp2", result)
```

With opencv and opencv-contrib 4.7.0.68, this [EDSR_x2.pb](https://github.com/Saafke/EDSR_Tensorflow/tree/master/models) file and this [image](https://file.io/UUh4uX3ClERp)

Unfortunately, this line generate an error:`result = sr.upsample(img)`

Error:

```
cv2.error: OpenCV(4.7.0) /io/opencv/modules/dnn/src/net_impl.cpp:1188: error: (-2:Unspecified error) in function 'void cv::dnn::dnn4_v20221220::Net::Impl::getLayerShapesRecursively(int, cv::dnn::dnn4_v20221220::Net::Impl::LayersShapesMap&)'
>  (expected: 'total(os[i]) > 0'), where
>     'total(os[i])' is -874068992
> must be greater than
>     '0' is 0
```

I tried to downgrade opencv and opencv-contrib to 4.6.0.66 and 4.5.5.64, same result.

Does anyone know why it doesn't work or has the same issue?

Comment: Please add some more information to make your issue reproducible. Please share your image and the source of your EDSR-file! [ask]

Answer (score 1):

You can try to start with a minimal working example:

```
import cv2


img = cv2.imread("img.png")
sr = cv2.dnn_superres.DnnSuperResImpl_create()
sr.readModel("models/EDSR_x2.pb")
sr.setModel("edsr", 2)
result = sr.upsample(img)
cv2.imwrite("out.png", result)
```

EDSR-file: https://github.com/Saafke/EDSR_Tensorflow/tree/master/models

OpenCV: opencv-contrib-python-4.7.0.68

Input:

[image]

Output:

[image]